# Curl URL with double quote

Tags: curl, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to formulate URL string in CURL request as:

```
curl -v --location --request GET "https://proxy-xxx.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/dev/proxy?path=\"https://target-xxx/api/v1/resource?q1=a&q2=b&q3=c\""
```

where I will pass `"https://target-xxx/api/v1/resource?q1=a&q2=b&q3=c\"` as query string to path variable in double quote.

Tested on API gateway console with `path="https://target-xxx/api/v1/resource?q1=a&q2=b&q3=c"` works fine.

However CURL hit bad request 400, and aws api gateway don't have received. I believe URL syntax problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quotations marks in the URL grammar do nothing special, do not mean a string literal. The first `"` does not mark unescaped string begin and the second `"` does not mark unescaped string end. You should url encode `&` characters to avoid splitting query params.

```
curl -v --location --request GET https://httpbin.org/get?path="https://target-xxx/api/v1/resource?q1=a%26q2=b%26q3=c"
```

Response:

```
{
  "args": {
    "path": "https://target-xxx/api/v1/resource?q1=a&q2=b&q3=c"
  },
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.79.1",
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-6215a80a-5e94b80531a2f4076f84342e"
  },
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/get?path=https:%2F%2Ftarget-xxx%2Fapi%2Fv1%2Fresource%3Fq1=a%26q2=b%26q3=c"
}
```

If you wish `path` quoted

```
curl -v --location --request GET https://httpbin.org/get?path=\"https://target-xxx/api/v1/resource?q1=a%26q2=b%26q3=c\"
```

Response:

```
{
  "args": {
    "path": "path": "\"https://target-xxx/api/v1/resource?q1=a&q2=b&q3=c\""
  },
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.79.1",
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-6215a9c5-11a283486ad54eb96c499bc7"
  },
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/get?path=\"https:%2F%2Ftarget-xxx%2Fapi%2Fv1%2Fresource%3Fq1=a%26q2=b%26q3=c\""
}
```

Comment: thanks for explain. once encoded &, it works!